# DI in Program.cs stopped working after upgrade .NET Core from 2 to 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

I have ASP.NET Core application where I need to get database credentials from external AWS service. Essentially, I need to inject CredentialRetrievalService into Startup.cs. Awhile ago, I found an [example](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/05/using-dependency-injection-with-startup-in-asp-net-core/) that describes perfectly how to do it:

In `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection =>
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

and in `Startup.cs`:

```
private ISomeService _someService;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ISomeService someService)
{
    _someService = someService;
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Just to see that everything works - and it does!
    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.MaxModelValidationErrors = _someService.GetNumber(Configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxModelValidationErrors"));
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Now I am trying to upgrade the application to ASP.NET Core **3**. I can see that there is [breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.1#hosting-generic-host-restricts-startup-constructor-injection), and the code above doesn't work any more. Recommended action is to Inject services into the `Startup.Configure` method instead. But what should I do if I need to invoke injected service in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: Is it a viable option for you to switch from `IWebHost BuildWebHost` to `IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder`? ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1))

Comment: @PeterCsala - yes, in Core 3 I am using `IHostBuilder`. With `IWebhost` it doesn't even compile. `BuildWebHost` / `CreateHostBuilder` is just a local function name in `Program` class

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the approach and taking advantage of dependency injection when configuring options

Reference [Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-di-services-to-configure-options)

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();        

    services.AddMvc(); //options will be configured lower down

    //Use DI services to configure MVC options
    services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
        .Configure<ISomeService>((options, someService) => {
            int value = Configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxModelValidationErrors");
            options.MaxModelValidationErrors = someService.GetNumber(value);
        });
        
    //...
}

//...
```

Comment: Thank you (sorry - I was out for few days). First, I think you mean `Configure(SomeService)`, not ISomeService, right? docs in the link show to pass the service type, not interface. If I do it that way - I am getting the following exception: `InvalidOperationException: No service for type SomeService has been registered.` Not sure, why or how the service has to be registered. FWIW, I *don't* have a parameterized constructor in SomeService, so registering a transient generic IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions> (as in docs) should work

Comment: @Felix I meant to use the interface. In the above answer I only omitted its registration as it was not shown in the original post.

Comment: @Felix you may need to reformat the question so we have a better idea of what you are **actually** trying to do. It appears you have left out some very relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

After more analysis, this is what seems to work:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IOptions<MvcOptions> options, ISomeService someService)
{
    // ...
    int value = Configuration.GetValue<int>("MaxModelValidationErrors");
    options.Value.MaxModelValidationErrors = someService.GetNumber(value);
    // ...
}
```

But it doesn't work with my *real* application where `SomeService` is `DbContext`

Comment: What does it mean: "does not work" in this particular case?